# Using sstream in to provide the name of output file in ofstream

Tags: c++

I am trying to use sstream to provide the name to the file in ofstream. But I am getting the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stringstream ss;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {ss<<"table"<<i;cout<<ss.str()<<endl;
        ofstream ofs(ss.str());

        ofs.close();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
temp2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temp2.cpp:10:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type)’
temp2.cpp:10:24: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:629:7: note: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:629:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:614:7: note: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:614:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:588:11: note: std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:588:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const std::basic_ofstream<char>&’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are using a pre-C++11 implementation of `std::ofstream`: in the original C++ standard the constructor of `std::ofstream` (and its relatives) didn't have a constructor taking a `std::string`. There was only a constructor from `char const*`. The work-around is to get a corresponding C-string from the `std::string`:

```
std::ofstream ofs(ss.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need use `string` , you can do this using :

`ofs << ss.rdbuf();`