# String stream error, not c_str

Tags: c++, linux

I have a piece of code which works in Visual Studio but will not compile on my university cluster. The cluster uses the icc compiler and my makefile is here:

```
CC=icc
DEPENDENCY = Polymer.h

%.o:%.c $(DEPENDENCY)
        $(CC) -03 -xSSE4.2 -axAVX, CORE-AVX-I, CORE-AVX2
PolymerExe: Main.o Polymer.o
        CC -o PoymerExe Main.o Polymer.o -I
```

The errors all seem to be related to string and so I will paste in only those bits that are relevant (it's a massive bit of code otherwise).

before main

```
#include"Polymer.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
```

inside main

```
stringstream myName;
myName << "DeltaGdependence_given" << "DeltaG_Pol" << DeltaG_Pol << ".txt";
ofstream aFile(myName.str);
aFile << deltaG << "\t" << Velocity << "\t" << Error_Given_R << "\t" << Error_Given_W << "\t" << Error << endl;
aFile.close();
```

I am getting an error very similar to this [Using sstream in to provide the name of output file in ofstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324095/using-sstream-in-to-provide-the-name-of-output-file-in-ofstream) but it is not working if I change it to myName.c_str

Full error for myName.str:

```
Main.cpp:27:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type)’
   ofstream aFile(myName.str());
                              ^
Main.cpp:27:30: note: candidates are:
In file included from Main.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:640:7: note: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       basic_ofstream(const char* __s,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:640:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:625:7: note: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
       basic_ofstream(): __ostream_type(), _M_filebuf()
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:625:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:599:11: note: std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char>&)
     class basic_ofstream : public basic_ostream<_CharT,_Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:599:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const std::basic_ofstream<char>&’
make: *** [Main.o] Error 1
```

if I change myName.str to myName.c_str I get this error in both visual studio and on the cluster.

```
Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Main.cpp:27:25: error: ‘std::stringstream’ has no member named ‘c_str’
   ofstream aFile(myName.c_str);
                         ^
make: *** [Main.o] Error 1
```

I have also tried it with just myName with the same error.
Thankyou for your time,
Jenny

Comment: Instead of `ofstream aFile(myName.str)` use `ofstream aFile(myName.str().c_str())`

Comment: `ofstream aFile(myName.str);` `str` is a function: so you should call it: `ofstream aFile(myName.str());` or `ofstream aFile(myName.str().c_str());`

Comment: "* I will paste in only those bits that are relevant (it's a massive bit of code otherwise)*"  The correct thing to do is to make a small program that exhibits your problem, and post that here instead.  You can read how to create a [mcve]; doing so will likely attract better answers to your question.

Comment: @TobySpeight Even more interestingly, the process of writing MCVE will often make the answer obvious and the question unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You may have two problems: The first and definitive problem is that you pass a pointer to the member function to the `std::ofstream` constructor. You do not *call* it. Do e.g.

```
ofstream aFile(myName.str());
//                       ^^
// Note parentheses to call the member function
```

instead.

The other possible problem is that the possibility to use `std::string` as arguments for the file stream `open` calls (and in the file stream constructors) came with the C++11 standard. Before that you could only use `const char*`.

So if the Intel C++ compiler support C++11 (or later) then you might need to add a flag when compiling to enable C++11 (or later). Or you have to pass a `const char*` when you open the file streams.